# Replacing Linux built-in cmp utility

Tags: c

Linux's `cmp` command compares two files, byte-by-byte, and return the first difference (or nothing if there is now difference).

What sort of something or other could be done to do this in C? Would it be as simple as comparing two calls of `getchar` or maybe `fscanf` and `break`ing as soon as a difference is found?

Comment: Why don't you look at the source of the `cmp` program? It's probably very simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Linux's cmp command compares two files, byte-by-byte ...
```

With some optimization:

```
Get the optimal block size of the files.
Find the rough position of the first difference by reading words, not bytes.
```

---

> Would it be as simple as comparing two calls of getchar or maybe
>   fscanf and breaking as soon as a difference is found?

It has some extras:

```
   -i, --ignore-initial=SKIP
          skip first SKIP bytes of both inputs

   -i, --ignore-initial=SKIP1:SKIP2
          skip first SKIP1 bytes of FILE1 and first SKIP2 bytes of FILE2

   -n, --bytes=LIMIT
          compare at most LIMIT bytes
```

---

You can take a look to cmp.c [[source code](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/gnudiff/gnudiff-10/diffutils/cmp.c?txt)]

Comment: Thank you. I downloaded the GNU utilities source and `cmp` was not included.